# ¿Cómo consigo que una resta de una variable se ejecute sólo cuando se hace OnClick?

Tags: php, variables

Estoy intentando hacer una página en la que hay tres botones. Sí pulsas el primero, se activa el segundo y resta 25 puntos a una variable, si pulsas el segundo resta 25 puntos y se activa el tercer botón. En caso de que pulse el tercer botón, la variable se queda a 0.

```
<div class="btn-group col-5 align-items-center" role="group" >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mx-auto active"onClick="document.getElementById('oculto').style.visibility='visible';<?php $puntuacion=75;?> document.getElementById('extra').disabled=false;">Pista Básica</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg mx-auto " id="extra" onClick="document.getElementById('oculto2').style.visibility='visible';<?php $puntuacion=50;?> document.getElementById('solucion').disabled=false;" disabled >Pista Extra</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mx-auto " id="solucion" onClick="document.getElementById('oculto3').style.visibility='visible';<?php $puntuacion=0 ?>" disabled>Solución</button>
        </div>
```

El problema es que, al hacer un echo para ver si funciona, me ejecuta las tres cosas aunque sólo le de a un botón y el resultado siempre es 0 ¿Alguien sabe como puedo arreglarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Edito: La variable está creada en el  con un valor inicial de 100 y no lo hago en Javascript porque es una variable que, en función de su resultado, tiene que ser enviada a una base de datos.

Gracias.

Comment: La variable cuánto vale al inicio?

Comment: No, no estoy usando Ajax, pero también te digo que no soy muy experimentado en todo eso y intento hacer las cosas con mis conocimientos. Suponía que sólo tenía que actualizar la variable en función del botón que se diera y eso me generaría el resultado esperado.

Comment: Puedes poner un name a cada button, y englobar los botones en un form. Luego desde php recojes el valor del botón pulsado y según cada uno actualizas la variable y vuelves a construir el formulario. No necesitas javascript para ello. Si lo quieres hacer sin recargar la página entonces si deberás plantearte ajax y demas

Answer (score 0):

PHP se ejecuta en un solo request. Cuando ves algo en tu browser (o la respuesta que sea por ajax o CLI), es porque PHP dice: "terminé, ahora mando mi respuesta". Y se olvida del tema.

Desde el front no hay manera de comunicarle al backend que una variable ha cambiado sin decírcelo expresamente en alguna clase de request (da igual si es ajax, http, websocket). Por lo tanto cuando pones:

```
 <div class="btn-group col-5 align-items-center" role="group" >
    <button type="submit" onClick="xxx.style.visibility='visible';<?php $puntuacion=75;?> xxx.disabled=false;"> 
       Pista Básica
    </button> 
 </div>
```

PHP lo procesa antes de imprimir y a vista suya ahí dice:

```
 echo '<div class="btn-group col-5 align-items-center" role="group" >';
 echo '   <button type="submit" onClick="xxx.style.visibility=\'visible\';
 $puntuacion=75;
 echo '   xxx.disabled=false;"> ';
 echo '      Pista Básica';
 echo '   </button> ';
 echo '</div>';
```

Luego la asignación del valor 75 se hace cuando PHP imprime. Al final de ese párrafo pasó por la línea que dice "$puntuacion = 0" y ese valor tiene la variable para cuando imprime.

Lo que debieras hacer, en cambio, es manejarlo todo por javascript y para persistir en BBDD, enviar la puntuación en el siguiente request

Algo como

```js
let puntuacion = 100,
  puntaje = document.getElementById('puntaje'),
  oculto = document.getElementById('oculto'),
  oculto2 = document.getElementById('oculto2'),
  oculto3 = document.getElementById('oculto3');

function pistaBasica() {
  puntuacion = 75;
  puntaje.innerText=puntuacion;
  oculto.classList.remove('invisible');
  document.getElementById('extra').disabled = false;
}

function pistaExtra() {
  puntuacion = 50;
  puntaje.innerText=puntuacion;
  oculto2.classList.remove('invisible');
  document.getElementById('solucion').disabled = false;
}

function verSolucion() {
  puntuacion = 0;
  puntaje.innerText=puntuacion;
  oculto3.classList.remove('invisible');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button class="btn btn-info  mx-auto active" onclick="pistaBasica()">Pista Básica</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning  mx-auto " id="extra" onclick="pistaExtra()" disabled>Pista Extra</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger   mx-auto " id="solucion" onclick="verSolucion()" disabled>Solución</button>
<b>Puntaje: <span id="puntaje">100</span></b>
<div class="invisible" id="oculto">Oro no es</div>
<div class="invisible" id="oculto2">Plata no es</div>
<div class="invisible" id="oculto3">Respuesta final: PLATANO</div>
```